# "Can't play this video" error AFTER the video finishes playing

Tags: stock-android

I get this error AFTER the video plays. This comes up when the video ends. And it was recorded on the same Pixel phone where I play it. Tried different apps to play the video, same result.

Answer (score 1):

Possible that the last few seconds are corrupt. Or maybe it's trying to play the next video and that one is corrupt